# ContentChildren, get the component and the native Element

Tags: angular

I have been looking for ages on the documentation and source code of Angular, but so far no luck.

```
import {
  ContentChildren,
  QueryList
} from '@angular/core';
import { AwesomeComponent } from './awesome.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'cool-dad',
  templateUrl: './cool-dad.template.html'
})
export class CoolDadComponent {
  @Input() loop = false;
  @Input() automatic = false;
  @ContentChildren(AwesomeComponent) items: QueryList<AwesomeComponent>;

  someFunc() {
    this.items.forEach(item => { console.log(item)});
  }
}
```

With the above code I get a reference to the component, I can set it's properties and call it's public methods. That's great, but I also need access to it's html properties, such as width, height, etc.

```
import {
  ContentChildren,
  ElementRef,
  QueryList
} from '@angular/core';
import { AwesomeComponent } from './awesome.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'cool-dad',
  templateUrl: './cool-dad.template.html'
})
export class CoolDadComponent {
  @Input() loop = false;
  @Input() automatic = false;
  @ContentChildren(AwesomeComponent, { read: ElementRef }) items: QueryList<AwesomeComponent>;

  someFunc() {
    this.items.forEach(item => { console.log(item)});
  }
}
```

With the above code I get the native element and therefore I can get access to all the html properties, but I loose all the access to the components methods.

How can I get both?

Comment: if you put both `@ContentChildren(AwesomeComponent) components` and `@ContentChildren(AwesomeComponent, { read: ElementRef }) elements`, doesn't work?

Comment: That was my last resource having two separate lists, I was hoping there was something less _hackish_

Comment: what makes you think it's hackish?

Comment: Having two lists with different representations of the same component. I will need to iterate two lists whenever I need to change some style and @Inputs

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply declare the following in the constructor of `AwesomeComponent:`

```
constructor(public elem: ElementRef) {}
```

This way you'll be able to access the public property elem and access the html properties of each component:

```
someFunc() {
 this.items.forEach(item => {console.log(item.elem.nativeElement.style.someHTMLProperty)});
}
```

Comment: @FabioAntunes, how does this answer the original question?

Comment: It looks at other perspective, Injects the `ElementRef` to the AwesomeComponent, that way I get the list of `AwesomeComponents` and I also get access to the NativeElement for each of one

Comment: @FabioAntunes, and it seems to use less _hackish_ than two lists? How are you supposed to access them in the parent component?

Comment: @Maximus Yes, It's just one list I can do this `this.items.forEach(item => { item.someFunc(); item.elem.nativeElement.style.width = '1337px'})`

Comment: @maximus Using the first method `@ContentChildren(AwesomeComponent) items: QueryList<AwesomeComponent>;` You get the component reference, so you have access to the components public properties and methods

Comment: @FabioAntunes, I see, I understand now. This is _a_ solution. But to me it goes against encapsulation. Child components should _know_ they are supposed to expose their elementref on class instance. I don't design applications that way...

Answer (score 4):

After hacking around to make this work on my own project, I realized why it's not supported natively in any obvious way: It's a bad idea.

If `CoolDadComponent` can actually change the HTML properties of `AwesomeComponent`, then it obviously needs to make various assumptions about that component and encapsulation goes belly-up. Also, view encapsulation rules could complicate styling.

So the correct way of doing this, is to let `CoolDadComponent` work with `@ContentChildren` and set properties on the `AwesomeComponent` instances. Those instances should manipulate their own HTML, preferably in a template or at least with `Renderer`.

```
export class CoolDadComponent {
// Other stuff as in OP
  @ContentChildren(AwesomeComponent) items: QueryList<AwesomeComponent>;
  someFunc() {
    this.items.forEach(item => item.configure({prop1: 'value', prop2: 'value'}));
  }
}
```

And in `AwesomeComponent`:

```
export class AwesomeComponent {
// Other stuff
  public configure(options: MyOptionsInterface) {
    // Set related properties
  }
```

It will also work if `CoolDadComponent` (bonus points for that name, by the way) simply sets the individual properties on `AwesomeComponent` directly.

Comment: Cool answer! Yeah that makes sense, I know in my example I'm changing the width, but what I'm really trying to achieve is to read the style properties of my AwesomeComponents, not mutating. Nevertheless I appreciate your investigation and I'm sure it will help any future readers.